# I want to do icon near receipt in purchase order icon display the number of recorded of function below depends on purchase order I write the function

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-15, odoo-16

This function to create Landed cost Bill in any purchase order
so I want to do icon to display number of records function for each purchase order  when I press to button `create_landed_cost_bill` must create and put the number in icon

```py
def create_landed_cost_bill(self):
        for purchase in self:
            picking_id = ''
            po_id = purchase.id
            po_no = purchase.name
            po_partner = purchase.partner_id.id
            po_order_line = purchase.order_line
            account_move_record_id = {
                'purchase_id': po_id,
                'ref': po_no,
                'partner_id': po_partner,
                'move_type': 'in_invoice',
            }
            account_move_id = self.env['account.move'].create(account_move_record_id)

logistic_bill_count = fields.Integer(string='Logistic Bill Count', compute='_compute_logistic_bill_count', store=True, compute_sudo=True)
  

    @api.depends('invoice_ids ')
    def _compute_logistic_bill_count(self):
        for order in self:
            order.logistic_bill_count = len(order.invoice_ids )


def create_landed_cost_bill(self):
        for purchase in self:
            picking_id = ''
            po_id = purchase.id
            po_no = purchase.name
            po_partner = purchase.partner_id.id
            po_order_line = purchase.order_line
            account_move_record_id = {
                'purchase_id': po_id,
                'ref': po_no,
                'partner_id': po_partner,
                'move_type': 'in_invoice',
            }
            account_move_id = self.env['account.move'].create(account_move_record_id)


 def action_view_logistic_bills(self):
        
        self.ensure_one()
        action = self.env.ref('account.action_move_in_invoice_type').read()[0]
        action['domain'] = [('purchase_order_id', '=', self.id)]
        return action
    
    def button_open_logistic_bills(self):
        self.ensure_one()  # Ensure that we are working with a single record
        action = self.action_view_logistic_bills()
        return action
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.